# how to create installer for Java that copies dll to JRE folder

Tags: java, installation

I created a program and I want to make an installer for it.
I have never done it before. Program uses `RXTXcomm.jar` and in order my program to work, some dll files has to be copied to JRE:

`rxtxSerial.dll` and `rxtxParallel.dll` to `<JAVA_HOME>\jre\bin`

so i wonder, how to make an installer that can copy these files?
I tried "Inno Setup 5" but i can't find how to do that.
I also tried "Advanced Installer" software, but can't figure it out so far.

Comment: you do understand this limits your application? dll is Microsoft, so basically: Windows only.
with installer, I assume you mean a 'setup.exe' or similar?
again: why writing Java code if you want your application to run in Windows only? there are better languages for that.

Comment: I would not be amused when an installer _changes_ other installations on my machine. Why don't you bundle an already set up JRE with your application?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Good idea. but correct me if i am wrong: this means my program gain additional ~120mb? so far it takes about 5mb

Answer (score 1):

Using Advanced Installer you can create a custom action (DLL or VBScript) which search for the  JAVA_HOME location and set the result into an installer property. You should add the custom action before the "CostFinalize" standard action. Then, you should create in "Files and Folders" page a property-based folder using the above installer property set by your custom action and add your DLL files under the property-based folder.

Comment: you can also add a bundled JRE http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-multiple-builds.html#set-jre-bundle

Comment: what if new version of java is released after i installed my app? these dll's stays in old Java folder, but my program tries to use new version of Java...?

Comment: There is no way to detect that a new JRE is installed and re-trigger the installation of your app. A better method is to bundle the JRE desired in your installer, so you app uses only that one: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-multiple-builds.html#set-jre-bundle